# Sequential monte carlo : A simple example

Tags: bayesian, monte-carlo, sequential-monte-carlo

I am attempting to understand how to implement the sequential monte carlo algorithm using this [article](https://www.sas.upenn.edu/~jesusfv/ejemplo.pdf). Here are the steps that the author proposes:

[image]

[image]

**Example problem**:

Say I have a self moving robot that measures distance from a wall. At some time T, the robot tells me how far away he is from that wall ( in meters ):

Time 0 : 3,3,4,5,6,4,3

Time 1 : 4,5,6,2,3,3,4

Time 2 : 6,5,3,4,5,6,7

**My Question**

How would I go about implementing the sequential monte carlo algorithm for the example problem I've defined above? ( A simple step by step process, for even just two iterations would help me out )

**My Thoughts**

I understand how to do Step 1, I'd just set N to 7, and use my particles for each time bin. If I was at T of 0, I'd use : 3,3,4,5,6,4,3.

Step 2, I do not understand. Do I take my particles and draw a line of best fit? ( To determine the underlying function? )

Step 3 and 4, I understand.

Step 5, I am unsure as to what "Resample with replacement N" means.

Step 6, I understand. I essentially move my time bin, capture the new 7 particles, and do steps 2-5 again.

Comment: The statistical model for the five-dimension data seems to be missing.

Comment: I added the url under the highlighted word : article .

Comment: Readers are not expected to read the link, the question should be self contained.

Comment: @Xi'an In my opinion, the question is self contained. I simply referenced where I got the material from, and left the algorithm defined by the author in the question. If there is something I can do to make it more clear, I am certainly game to edit it to best favor the community.

Comment: You cannot do (2) because you neglected a crucial piece of information: "For simplicity we assume that $x_0$ is known."  Thus, (2) is a simple formula in which you plug in each value of $w^{1\mid 0, i}$ to compute the corresponding $x^{1\mid 0, i}.$ Your *statistical* question then reduces to "Given a set of values and corresponding probabilities, how do I sample from them with replacement?" [This search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=sample+replacement+weight*) turns up many promising answers. Check them out and let us know if you have anything further to ask.

Comment: @whuber I'll do some more research and re-formulate my question. Sample with replacement seems to be only one step in the original paperwork of particle filtering. Thanks for the clarification.